# Как добавить angular workspace в сущестувующий проект?

Tags: angular2, архитектура, консоль

есть существующий проект со всеми настройками, который успешно работает. Хочу создать angular worksapce в котором будет старый проект, новый проект, и папка с либами(хочу переиспользовать ui-компоненты). Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом я могу добавить workspace и какие настройки прописать в angular.json.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел таки нужную статью где все толково описано - https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527